# Wrong Emulator Scale

Tags: android, eclipse, emulation

As shown on the picture, my emulator is completely wrong because I can see only the middle of the actual screen, like if the scale of the phone was wrong. I already tried changing the scale and the screen size but none works. I'm using Eclipse.

[image: Wrong Emulator]

Comment: try this: when you start emulator, uncheck option `scale display to real size`

Comment: already tried still doesn't work

Comment: go to edit avd and change your avd skin to `skin with dynamic hardware controls`, try different screens.